# Line starting with # is not treated as a comment for MySQL in H2

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, h2, flyway

I am using `flyway` with my `SpringBoot` app. The database is `MySQL`. The comments in the flyway scripts start with `#`.

When I try to write an `H2` test, it fails to load ApplicationContext with an error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
Migration V0_0_1__init.sql failed
-------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 42000
Message    : Syntax error in SQL statement "[*]# types
INSERT INTO `users`.`TYPES` (NAME) VALUES (""Bob"") "; SQL statement:
# Types
INSERT INTO `users`.`types` (name) VALUES ("Bob") [42000-199]
Location   : db/migration/V0_0_1__init.sql (/myapp/target/classes/db/migration/V0_0_1__init.sql)
Line       : 1
Statement  : # Types
INSERT INTO `users`.`types` (name) VALUES ("Bob")
```

From what I was able to understand, `H2` does not treat lines starting with `#` as comments but `MySQL` does. Is there a way to get `H2` to treat `#` in the `SQL` scripts as comments?

I even have the mode set to `MySQL` in my `application-test.properties` and the test using the `h2-test` profile.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:myapp;MODE=MySQL;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS myapp;
```

Comment: H2 supports only standard `--` and `/* */` comments and also non-standard `//` comments and has no configuration settings for them. MySQL supports both types of standard comments and also non-standard `#` comments. You should use only the standard comments to avoid such issues. Don't use vendor-specific features when the same goal can be easily achieved with standard SQL, especially when you use multiple database systems.

Answer (score 1):

As said by Evgenij Ryazanov, H2 supports only comments in the form:

```
-- anything
// anything
/* anything */
```

Look at the [H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#comments) for details.

You should then stick to [standard SQL92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt) comment which is `--` and modiy your SQL initialization scripts accordingly.